# Binary Search on a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I have a 2D array which is fully sorted. The arrays below are examples

```
    1  2  3  
    5  6  7  
    9 10 11
```

and

```
    1  2  3  4  5
    6  7  8  9  10
```

I would like to use binary search on these array. Let `rows` be the number of rows and `cols` be the number of columns

Initially `start = 0` and `end = rows * cols -1`

In the 3 X 3 array above, midpoint works out to be four  [9 elements].  Now how do I find out the corresponding row and column with the midpoint ? Is there any standard formula for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is pretty simple:

```
row = number/cols_per_row;
col = number%cols_per_row;
```

Comment: Hmm ..Just curious.How did you come up with this ?

Comment: Well for each cols_per_row numbers you go one row down. So this explains why the first number is found using this formula, right? As for the second one - the column in which you are is cyclic repeating every cols_per_row numbers, so `%` describes such behavior, right?

Comment: @ThorstenKranz the number of cols that the OP has per row. As he/she has not specified a variable that stores this number I simply used this notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let `size = rows * cols`

`mid = size // 2` (integer division)

`row = mid // cols`

`col = mid % cols` (rest for integer division)